# метод поиска BST ((итеративно)), возвращающий узел, содержащий искомое значение и его предшественника

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево, бинарный-поиск

Я уже написал несколько методов, связанных с моей проблемой. Сейчас у меня есть два метода, написанных с использованием рекурсии (addBSTRecursion (int element) и searchBSTRecursion (int element)). И теперь мне нужно реализовать (итеративно) метод поиска BST (Pair <BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST (int element)), возвращающий узел, содержащий искомое значение и его предшественник.

- если искомый элемент отсутствует в дереве, первый элемент пары равен нулю.
- если первый элемент пары является корнем (у него нет предшественника), то второй элемент пары равен нулю.
  Вот мой класс Pair:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    public T1 first;
    public T2 second;

    public Pair(T1 a, T2 b) {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }
}
```

Вот как мне удалось реализовать метод (Pair <BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST (int element)), но, к сожалению, он не работает должным образом.

```
@Override
public Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element) {
    int current = 0;
    while (element != data) {
        if (element < data) {
            current = left.data;
        } else {
            current = right.data;
        }
    }
    Pair pair = new Pair(element, current);
    return pair;
}
```

К примеру у меня есть следущее бинарное дерево(это дерево как раз у меня в программе):

```
        1
    3
            4
        6
            7
8
    10
            13
        14
```

Что я хочу получить по выполнению метода (`Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element)`)
Например когда я выполню `object.searchBSTRecursion(6)` (где `object` - обьект класса `Node`), в консоле я хочу получить следующее:

```
6, 3
```

Где `6` - узел который я написал для поиска, а `3` - это его родительский узел
Если я бы выполнил следующее `object.searchBSTRecursion(8)`, я хотел бы получить:

```
8, null
```

Где `8` - узел который я написал для поиска, а `null` - я получил потому что у этого узла нету родительского
Так же если я выполню например `object.searchBSTRecursion(25)` (а такого узла вообще нету в моем дереве), то я должен получить следующее:

```
null, null
```

Где первый null - потому что узел который я подал для поиска - не существует, а второй - null - потому что если нету узла которого я ищу, то и родительского узла у него тоже нету.
Сейчас же, когда я проверяю работу своего метода, то вообще получаю какой то бесконечный цикл `while` с его то условием. (Не советую запускать этот метод, без его модификации)
Если честно, пока не знаю, как правильно реализовать этот метод, буду рад любым подсказкам. А также внизу я добавляю остальные классы.

```
public abstract class BinaryTreeNode {
    protected int data; // value stored in the node
    protected BinaryTreeNode left, right; // left and right sub-trees

    // constructor
    public BinaryTreeNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // recursively adds an item to the BST
    // @param new data to be stored in the new node
    public abstract void addBSTRecursion(int element);

    // prints the tree
    // for example, for a tree:
    //        7
    //    6        8
    // 2     7  4     9
    //
    // write:
    //
    //      2
    //   6
    //      7
    // 7
    //      4
    //   8
    //      9

    // method pseudocode
    // if there is a left subtree then print the left one (recursive call)
    // write out gaps (depending on level), write out data, go to new line
    // if it is right, print the right one (recursive call)
    // @param level the distance of the node from the root. We start from 0.
    public abstract void print(int level);

    // recursive searches the BST.
    // returns true if it finds an element with the given value
    // @param searched value searched
    // @return true if the given value is in the tree, false otherwise
    public abstract boolean searchBSTRecursion(int element);

    // iterative lookup of values in the BST
    // returns a pair: node containing the searched element and its predecessor.
    // if the searched element is not in the tree, the first element of the pair is null.
    // if the first element of the pair is a root (it has no predecessor), then the second element of the pair is null.
    // @param searched value searched
    // @return pair of nodes: the first is the node containing the value searched for, or null if not found;
    // the second element of the pair is the parent of the node (or null if the value is at the root of the tree)
    public abstract Pair < BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode > searchBST(int element);
}
```

```
public class Node extends BinaryTreeNode {
    public Node(int data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBSTRecursion(int element) {
        Node node = new Node(element);
        if (element < data) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.addBSTRecursion(element);
            } else {
                left = node;
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null) {
                right.addBSTRecursion(element);
            } else {
                right = node;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int level) {
        if (left != null) {
            left.print(level + 4);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(data + "\n");

        if (right != null) {
            right.print(level + 4);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean searchBSTRecursion(int element) {
        if (element == data) {
            return true;
        } else if (element < data) {
            if (left != null && left.searchBSTRecursion(element)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null && right.searchBSTRecursion(element)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element) {
        int current = 0;
        while (element != data) {
            if (element < data) {
                current = left.data;
            } else {
                current = right.data;
            }
        }
        Pair pair = new Pair(element, current);
        return pair;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node(8);

        node.addBSTRecursion(3);
        node.addBSTRecursion(10);

        node.addBSTRecursion(1);
        node.addBSTRecursion(6);

        node.addBSTRecursion(14);

        node.addBSTRecursion(4);
        node.addBSTRecursion(7);

        node.addBSTRecursion(13);


        node.print(0);

        System.out.print(node.searchBSTRecursion(15));
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код не компилируется.

Comment: в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Откуда я знаю, в чем проблема, что Вы поместили в вопрос код, который не компилируется?

Comment: @Igor, отредактировал вопрос, попробуйте сейчас!

Comment: Вы шутите? Я не буду ничего "пробовать". Если я вижу, что в вопросе код, который не скомпилируется (глазами, без никакого компилирования), я ставлю минус и голосую за закрытие вопроса. Это Вам повезло, что я сегодня добрый и написал за что минус.

Comment: Я проверил у себя, и все работает, возможно у вас проблемы с компилятором, не знаю...

Comment: Вы, видимо, не прочитали мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Я только что скопировал код со всех классов, который разместил здесь, в воросе, и все компилируется, так что... Только проблема с методом `Pair <BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST (int element)`, но его я и не вызываю в `Main`, классе, а вопрос по этому и задан, что в чем то есть проблема)

Comment: "Только проблема с методом" - я понятия не имею что это значит. И гадать не буду.

Comment: Я и не заставляю, просто зачем заходить на вопрос, и ставить минус, если не умеешь помочь с решением проблемы? Лучше поставить плюс, и тогда вопрос будет популярние, и его увидят люди с лучшими знаниями, и помогут

Comment: Я не буду ставить плюс плохому вопросу. "он не работает должным образом" - что это значит?

Comment: Сейчас я поправлю вопрос, наведу примеры что я получаю, и чего хочу получить.

Comment: А Вы говорите, что я не умею помочь. Я уже Вам помогаю, только Вы этого пока не понимаете.

Comment: @Igor, помогаете, поправил вопрос!

Comment: Пожалуйста. И что важно - Вы сами написали эту функцию, а не какой-то дядя из интернета дал Вам код.

Comment: @как мне связаться с Вами, дайте какой-то контакт с Вами, жду ответа!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element) {
    int current = 0;
    while (element != data) {
        if (element < data) {
            current = left.data;
        } else {
            current = right.data;
        }
    }
    Pair pair = new Pair(element, current);
    return pair;
}
```

Как может "работать" метод, у которого в сигнатуре объявлен возвращаемый тип `Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode>`, а возвращать Вы пытаетесь `new Pair(element, current);` с двумя целыми?

```
  return new Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode>(current, parent);
```

Теперь про цикл `while`.

Предположим, `element` не равен `data`. Так он и не станет ей никогда равным, так как ни `element` ни `data` в цикле не меняются. Таким образом, этот цикл никогда не закончится. Значит `current` должен быть не ноль (откуда здесь, вообще, ноль? почему ноль?), a

```
BinaryTreeNode current = this;
```

Так как Вам нужен еще и родитель, то понадобится еще одна локальная переменная

```
BinaryTreeNode parent = null;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132267/discussion-on-answer-by-igor---bst---).